# Visual Studio Ignoring MSBuild file (csproj) Customizations

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

*Note: Visual Studio 2010 SP1 / MSBuild 4.0*

I'm going crazy over this bug, I cannot understand why Visual Studio is behaving this way. I'm writing a custom `.targets` file for my projects in a particular solution. I've edited the `.csproj` file to have:

```
<Include Project="..\MyTargets.targets" />
```

After `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` near the bottom of the file. The idea is that this targets file will inject actions to be performed by modifying the `_____DependsOn` properties just like how [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp) integrates itself.

After scratching my head at how my targets would not run I decided to run it in the command line with MSBuild and see the nicely formatted color output.

In the command line, **my targets run**. From visual studio (even using clean/rebuild), **my targets do not run**.

I've hooked `BuildDependsOn` to run my targets like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildDependsOn>
    MyTargetGoesHere;
    $(BuildDependsOn)
  </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

My first thought is that i've got the wrong file. I verified the file, it's the right one. Then I checked to see if it was stale. Let visual studio make some changes, saved, ran. Visual studio's new changes took effect, still didn't run my targets.

So here I'm getting desperate. I put a **BLARING SYNTAX ERROR** in my targets file. MSBuild explodes, Visual Studio compiles the project successfully.

- What am I doing wrong?
- Does Visual Studio not use the MSBuild file?
- Does it call some super secret target instead of "Build" from `Microsoft.Common.targets`?
- Why would msbuild behave one way and studio another, I thought they were designed to work together...

Comment: did you close and reopen your solution file after making changes to the .targets file?

Comment: Interesting, does Visual Studio cache msbuild files or something? I hadn't closed the solution but I had re-loaded the projects many times.

Comment: VS will cache any msbuild files imported by projects.  Changes to the projects themselves will cause a reload of the project, but not a reload of the imported files, which is why a solution reload is needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To summarize the comments above, changes to imported project files do not trigger a reload, nor do changes to the importing project cause a reload of the imports.  A solution file reload is needed to capture changes made in an import.

Comment: I feel really dumb for not thinking to reload the solution, I assumed reloading the project was enough. It's nice to have clarification that VS caches. Thanks

Comment: Similar issue and reloading the solution doesn't even work for me.  In my ".psproj" file (PowerShell project) I have a blaring `<Error Text="Blah" />` in my build target; msbuild fails, but build from Visual Studio 2013 succeeds with zero output...